# O que é uma migrate?

Tags: python, django

Sou um iniciante no mundo django e uma das primeiras coisas que me deparo nos tutorias é o termo `migrate` eu gostaria de saber a que se refere isso, como usar e para que serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "migrate" (migração) serve para vocẽ gerenciar a estrutura das tabelas do banco de dados da sua aplicação, ou seja, através dela é possível incluir, alterar e excluir tabelas ou campos de determinada tabela, de uma forma organizada, deixando todas essas alterações documentadas e evitando que você a faça manualmente.

Para fazer uma migração é preciso gerar um arquivo migrate, e dentro dele, colocamos uma ou mais alterações que precisam ser feitas no nosso banco de dados, e quando vocẽ rodar essa migração, essas alterações serão feitas automaticamente.

As migrações são enumeradas de forma crescente, e é possível voltar ao número desejado, ou seja, você pode desfazê-la a qualquer momento, e voltar o seu banco de dados ao estado anterior de qualquer migração.

[Documentação Oficial sobre Migrações no Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/)